# JMeter: How to supply a hostname which contains a forward slash in JMeter user defined variables?

Tags: jmeter, hostname

The hostname being supplied to the JMeter test plan, contains a forward slash and has been defined in the User defined variables section. However, each time the test is run, the following is seen in the response message:

```
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Illegal character found in host: '/'
```

The hostname provided:
Jmetertest.com/test

Is there any way around this? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Show your HTTP request, You can put `/test` in path field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [DNS hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) cannot contain slash.

> The Internet standards (Request for Comments) for protocols specify that labels may contain only the ASCII letters a through z (in a case-insensitive manner), the digits 0 through 9, and the hyphen-minus character ('-'). The original specification of hostnames required that labels start with an alpha character, and not end with a hyphen

So you need to split hostname from the [URL Path](https://zvelo.com/anatomy-of-full-path-url-hostname-protocol-path-more/#pathfile)

i.e. in the following URL:

```
https://example.com/foo?bar=baz
```

- `https` - the protocol
- `example.com` - is the hostname
- `/foo` is the path
- `?bar=baz` is the query string

In the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler you can only have the following syntax:

[image]

If you put anything than allowed characters into "Server name of IP" field you will get an error.

Theoretically it's possible to put the full URL into the "Path" field like:

[image]

But in this case configuration elements like [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter/) may stop working.